# Método usando thread e herança JAVA

Tags: java

Estou tentando criar uma classe BolaDeFutebol que recebe atributos da classe pai Bola, a classe bola possui os atributos

```
private int ar = 100; //100%
private boolean furada = false;
```

Classe Bola(não possui imports):

```
public class Bola {

    private int ar = 100;
    private boolean furada = false;


    public Bola() {
    }


    public Bola(int ar, boolean furada) {
        this.ar = ar;
        this.furada = furada;
    }


    public int getAr() {
        return ar;
    }
    public void setAr(int ar) {
        this.ar = ar;
    }
    public boolean isFurada() {
        return furada;
    }
    public void setFurada(boolean furada) {
        this.furada = furada;
    }



}
```

Classe BolaDeFutebol(não possui imports):

```
public class BolaDeFutebol extends Bola{

    private String material = "Capotão";
    private String esporte = "Futebol";

    public BolaDeFutebol(String material, String esporte) {
        super();
        this.material = material;
        this.esporte = esporte;
    }

    public BolaDeFutebol() {
    }


    public String getMaterial() {
        return this.material;
    }
    public void setMaterial(String material) {
        this.material = material;
    }
    public String getEsporte() {
        return this.esporte;
    }
    public void setEsporte(String esporte) {
        this.esporte = esporte;
    }


    public void Mostrar(){
        System.out.println("Quantidade de ar: " + super.getAr() + "%");
        System.out.println("Furada status: " + super.isFurada());
        System.out.println("Material: " + getMaterial());
        System.out.println("Esporte: " + getEsporte());
    }

    public void Mostrar(int ar){
        System.out.println("Quantidade de ar: " + super.getAr() + "%");
    }


    public void Furar(){
        setFurada(true);
        int ar = getAr();
        new Thread(){
            @Override
            public void run() {
                for(int i = 0; i < ar; setAr(ar--)){
                    try {
                        Mostrar(ar);
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {

                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                super.run();
            }
        }.start();
    }
}
```

Está tudo funcionando, porem neste método(furar) da classe BolaDeFutebol eu não consigo subtrair o valor do atributo ar:

```
    public void Furar(){
        setFurada(true);
        int ar = getAr();
        new Thread(){
            @Override
            public void run() {
                for(int i = 0; i < ar; setAr(ar--)){
                    try {
                        Mostrar(ar);
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {

                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                super.run();
            }
        }.start();
    }
```

A cada 1 segundo quero que a bola vá perdendo ar, porém, não consigo alterar o valor da variável ar, estou um pouco enferrujado com superclasses em java gostaria de ajuda e saber aonde estou errando.

Classe de teste(não possui imports):

```
public class UsaBola {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        BolaDeFutebol bola = new BolaDeFutebol();
        bola.Mostrar();
        bola.Furar();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Em classes anônimas, como a que é criada implicitamente pela *thread*, as variáveis devem ser `final`, ou seja, constantes. Por esse motivo, o compilador não permite a você alterar a variável `ar`.

Para o seu programa funcionar, basta tirar essa criação de *thread*, que é desnecessária, e chamar apenas o `Thread.sleep()`, que vai rodar em cima da *main thread* na qual seu programa é executado:

Seu método furar() fica assim:

```
public void Furar() throws InterruptedException{
    setFurada(true);
    int ar = getAr();
    for (int i = 0; i <= ar; setAr(--ar)) {
        Mostrar(ar);
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    }
}
```

Além de eliminar a criação de *threads*, alterei a condição de parada do *loop* para `<=`, e também o incremento `(--ar)`, para que a exibição da porcentagem ocorresse corretamente tanto no início do furo quanto no fim.

O *output* do seu programa ficou assim:

```
Quantidade de ar: 100%
Furada status: false
Material: Capotão
Esporte: Futebol
Quantidade de ar: 100%
Quantidade de ar: 99%
Quantidade de ar: 98%
Quantidade de ar: 97%
[...]
Quantidade de ar: 2%
Quantidade de ar: 1%
Quantidade de ar: 0%
```

Se sobrou dúvida, só perguntar.

Comment: Muito obrigado sua resposta me ajudou muito a entender, aprendi muito com ela